# How to return a certain boolean value in a recursive function?

Tags: c++, recursion

I want to make a recursive function that determines if a string's characters all consist of alphabets or not. I just can't figure it out. Here's what I've done so far but it doesn't work properly.

```
bool isAlphabetic(string s){
const char *c = s.c_str();
if ((!isalpha(c[0]))||(!isalpha(c[s.size()])))
{
    return false;
}
else if (isalpha(c[0]))
{
    isAlphabetic(c+1);
    return true;
}
}
```

can anyone suggest a correct way?

Comment: "but it doesn't work properly" how does it not work? wrong result? crashes?

Comment: it returns false in every test case

Comment: Why do you need recursion for this in 1st place? Doesn't a simple `for()` loop fit, to solve the problem?

Comment: `!isalpha(c[s.size()])` makes no sense; why are you testing if the null terminator is an alphanumeric character? (Hint: it's never an alphanumeric character.) Also, you need to `return isAlphabetic(c+1);` instead of calling it and then returning true; you're just ignoring the result of the recursive call.

Comment: @Joey12 Have you stepped through with a debugger to see whats going on? (Hint see cdhowie's comment)

Answer (score 2):

Leaving aside the many partial strings you'll create (consider passing in just the string and a starting index instead), the `isalpha(c[s.size()])` check will always fail, since that's the `\0` at the end of the string.  You're also ignoring the result of the recursive calls.

```
bool isAlphabetic(string s){
  if (s.size() < 1)
    return true;               // empty string contains no non-alphas

  const char *c = s.c_str();

  if (!isalpha(c[0]))
  {
    return false;              // found a non-alpha, we're done.
  }
  else
  {
    return isAlphabetic(c+1);  // good so far, try the rest of the string
  }
}
```

Comment: What if you started with the empty string? I think that would break this. It needs and extra logic step to check for the empty string.

Comment: Just caught that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Building on [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27450824/501250), here is a fixed implementation that won't copy any portion of the string. It accomplishes this by passing a reference to the `string` object and an index to the character to check; recursion simply adds 1 to this index to check the next character, and so on until the end of the string is found.

I have removed your call to `c_str()` since it isn't needed. `string` can be directly indexed.

```
bool isAlphabetic(string const & s, int startIndex = 0) {
    // Terminating case: End of string reached. This means success.
    if (startIndex == s.size()) {
        return true;
    }

    // Failure case: Found a non-alphabetic character.
    if (!isalpha(s[startIndex])) {
        return false;
    }

    // Recursive case: This character is alphabetic, so check the rest of the string.
    return isAlphabetic(s, startIndex + 1);
}
```

Note that the empty string is considered alphabetic by this function. You can change this by changing `return true` to `return !s.empty()`.

Comment: You could return false for empty strings by changing `return true` to `return !s.empty()` ... though returning true is probably better, with the meaning of isAlphabetic being "for all c in s, c is alpha", which is true of the empty set.

Comment: @JimBalter Indeed, that's not a bad option if that is the desired behavior. Added this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here a working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool isAlphabetic(string s)
{
    if( s.empty() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    cout << "checking: " << s[0] << endl;

    if( isalpha(s[0]) )
    {
        return true;
    }

    return isAlphabetic(&s[0]+1);
}

int main()
{
    string word0 = "test";
    if( isAlphabetic(word0) )
    {
        cout << word0 << " is alphabetic" << endl; 
    }
    else
    {
        cout << word0 << " is NOT alphabetic" << endl; 
    }

    string word1 = "1234";
    if( isAlphabetic(word1) )
    {
        cout << word1 << " is alphabetic" << endl; 
    }
    else
    {
        cout << word1 << " is NOT alphabetic" << endl; 
    }

    string word2 = "1234w";
    if( isAlphabetic(word2) )
    {
        cout << word2 << " is alphabetic" << endl; 
    }
    else
    {
        cout << word2 << " is NOT alphabetic" << endl; 
    }

   return 0;
}
```